# My Mysql select query runs slower each time it is run

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I have 2 tables, **People** and **postcodelatlng**. 
 I have around 2,300 records in people which include their postcodes, as well as two empty columns for Lat & Lng coordinates. 
**postcodelatlng** is a table with around 1.6 million rows containing every single postcode in the UK as well as their respective coordinates.
I am trying to fill out the coordinates in the people table by matching the postcodes. This works fine when not using a limit roughly 0.15 second for each person. Unfortunately, as soon as I put the limit on, each time I run the query, the execution time almost doubles.

```
SELECT people.ID, people.Postcode, postcodelatlng.latitude, postcodelatlng.longitude 
FROM people 
INNER JOIN postcodelatlng 
ON people.Postcode=postcodelatlng.postcode 
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: including your table structure, as well as defined keys and indizes (+ some sample data), might be helpful.

Comment: In my experience long time ago with MySQL such problems were 100% of memory fragmentation caused by setting buffers too big. I could be completely wrong. But it may help if you post output of "show variables" and "show stats".

Comment: What are you trying to do with the LIMIT, as there is no ORDER BY, it may be completely random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to add two indexes, since 0.15 sec per row seems a high number. One on each Postcode Field:

```
CREATE INDEX ppl_postcode ON people(Postcode) using HASH;
CREATE INDEX postcode_ll ON postcodelatlng(postcode) using HASH;
```

It should run much faster now.

Comment: You might also want to check `EXPLAIN` in mySQL. [See the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: You are a life saver dude. I have been stuck on this for so long!

Comment: @JacobRiches Remember the rule, EACH side of the = for the JOIN needs an index for performance.  I like Boppy's use of HASH for the index.

Comment: HASH?  No such thing in MySQL (except for ENGINE=MEMORY`).  Anyway, BTree is a good substitute.